# Using Reflection to create automatically a List of Delegates

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have a Class called Operations.cs with some method. I want to create a List of Delegates to pick a method randomly. Right now I have the following working solution:

```
public delegate void Delmethod(ExampleClass supervisor);
public static Operations op = new Operations();
public List<Delmethod> opList = new List<Delmethod>();

opList.Add(op.OpOne);
opList.Add(op.OpTwo);
opList.Add(op.OpThree);
opList.Add(op.OpFour);
opList.Add(op.OpFive);
opList.Add(op.OpSix);
opList.Add(op.OpSeven);
```

But what I really want is generate the List opList automatically in the case I add a new method in the Operations.cs. I was trying to use reflection in an atempt to solve my problem as follows:

```
List<MethodInfo> listMethods = new List<MethodInfo>(op.GetType().GetMethods().ToList());

foreach (MethodInfo meth in listMethods)
{
   opList.Add(meth);
}
```

I believe that this doesn't work because I'm making a confusion about the meaning of delegate, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What are you going to do with this list? If you want to invoke these methods at some point, you'll need to specify the required arguments (which implies that you'll need to know the number and types of arguments to be supplied...).

Comment: Later I will randomly pick an Operation in opList to be invoked. The actual solution is something like:

Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.Next(opList.Count());
opList[random].Invoke(supervisor);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a delegate from particular method info.
Assuming, that `Operations` has only public instance methds with the same signature, the code will look like this:

```
public static Operations op = new Operations();
public List<Action<ExampleClass>> opList = new List<Action<ExampleClass>>();

oplist.AddRange(op
    .GetType()
    .GetMethods()
    .Select(methodInfo => (Action<ExampleClass>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<ExampleClass>), op, methodInfo)));
```

Note, that you don't need to declare `Delmethod`, since there is [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: e.g., opList[0](new ExampleClass())

Comment: That solutions works, but not for my case, because I only want in my opList certain methods of the class Operations

Comment: Could you formulate a criteria to search for the methods? Actually, in this case you just need to filter reflected methods, using given criteria.